# Performance issue when calling canvas.drawImage()

Tags: performance, html5-canvas

My source is far too big so I will only paste the relevant part.

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = "test.svg";

canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0, widthIncremented, heightIncremented);
```

Now this runs inside `requestAnimationFrame`. What the code does is, make the image bigger and bigger, making it appear to become closer.

In firefox and edge it runs really slow on low end devices. Im wondering, how can we optimize this process? Is it slow since it is converting svg to bitmap everytime? Too many pixels?

Comment: I guess we would need a bit more of context, like what is inside or outside the loop for example, the image size... And, is it normal the `canvas.drawImage()` instead of `context.drawImage()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of draw a bigger image, you can [scale canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_scale)